# Set line spacing between lines of a list using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

all,

Here's the documentation I'm looking at: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/paragraph-style#setspacebelowspace

I'm trying to edit a Google Slides presentation with a script, and specifically, I'm trying to create a numbered list in a text box, with 1.15 spaced lines, and 10 pixels between each list item. The code is below - recapBox is the text box in question.

```
var lines = recapBox.getText().getListParagraphs();
lines.forEach(function(line) {
  line.getRange().getParagraphStyle().setLineSpacing(115).setSpaceBelow(10);
});
```

It turns out, setLineSpacing(115) appears to work. However, doing setSpaceBelow only sets a 10-pixel space below the entire list, not below each individual list item. Can anyone help me figure out how to do it for each item?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/spacing-mode

```
var lines = recapBox.getText().getListParagraphs();
lines.forEach(function(line) {
   line.getRange().getParagraphStyle().setSpacingMode(SlidesApp.SpacingMode.NEVER_COLLAPSE).setLineSpacing(115).setSpaceBelow(10);
});
```